# Looking to sort Google Sheet data by the Position of a Person

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

So, the basis of what I am attempting to do is have the sheet "Employee Hours" order the rows dependant on the persons position in "Column D" - So, for example if an individuals rank is changed to Assistant Manager, Senior Staff, they will be ordered correctly.

Either works, either formula's or google script

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wuL8rJd0zaGQROF5rhB_S9Xiv6eo8x6uOCd64gWcexM/edit?usp=sharing

I have attempted some forumlas, and tried looking up some scripts but nothing to help.

Answer (score 0):

On a new sheet create a staff seniority table, something like this:

| Title | Seniority |
| --- | --- |
| President | 1 |
| Manager | 3 |
| Undermanager | 4 |
| Vice President | 2 |
| Staff | 5 |
| Gopher | 6 |

Then create a named range over the data rows and call it `Seniority`

On your staff listing page add a new column called Seniority and populate it with a lookup from this range:

| Job Title | Seniority | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Manager | =vlookup(A1,Seniority,2, false) | Joe Bloggs |
| President | =vlookup(A2,Seniority,2, false) | John Doe |

You can now sort the sheet (or just some range) by the Seniority column, and the Job Titles will appear in the correct order.
You can hide the Seniority column for cosmetic purposes if it suits you.

This can be automated by some script that fits with your other code. I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Will this automatically arrange it on the main sheet though?

Comment: No. For that you need to sort the data. You can automate the sort operation with a short script. You'll need to do that yourself, because 1) you already have some code attached, and 2) You need to decide at what point to perform the sort.

Comment: I hate to be that guy - But, with the sort code, how would I do such - I would like for it to sort as soon as something is changed on that sheet. For example, a new person is added, or their rank changes. The current code I have script-wise is just a simple clear data script.

Comment: You should edit that information into the question. I have demonstrated a technique for sorting data into some non-standard order. If you need to do that and automate with script, say so in the question instead of expecting someone to revise their answer in response to emerging requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorting based upon position**

gs:

```
function sortBasedUponPosition() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//data sheet
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//output sheet
  const dsr = 11;//data start row
  const dsc = 4;//data start col
  const vs = sh.getRange(dsr, 4, sh.getLastRow() - dsr + 1, sh.getLastRow() - dsc + 1).getValues();
  const so = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => ( a.pA = [...new Set([...a.pA, r[0]])], a), { pA: [],so:function(){
    let obj = this.pA.reduce((ac,pos,idx) => (ac[pos] = idx, ac),{})
  return obj;} }).so();//function inside of object
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(so));
  let end = "is near";
  vs.sort((a,b) => so[a[0]]-so[b[0]]);//the  actual sorting
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));//sorted
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);//displayed on another sheet
}
```

Sort Object:

```
{"Manager":0,"Assistant Manager":1,"Director Of Operations":2,"Senior Staff":3,"Trial Senior Staff":4,"Staff":5,"Trial Phase":6}
```

Data:

|  | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Employee Rank | Employee Name | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday | Total Hours | Pay |
| 11 | Manager | Juno Meeh |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 12 | Assistant Manager | Britt Nicole |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 13 | Director Of Operations | Darby Way |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 14 | Senior Staff | Sheeza Bati |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 15 | Senior Staff | Maelynn Kowaldi |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 16 | Senior Staff | Oli Sax |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 17 | Trial Senior Staff | Itachi Okamoto |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 18 | Staff | Barry Mosley |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 19 | Staff | Enzo Zepelli |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 20 | Staff | Joey Gambino |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 21 | Staff | Johnny Gambino |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 22 | Staff | Maddie Madison |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 23 | Staff | Madisyn Hope |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 24 | Staff | Nickoli Litchnovsky |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 25 | Staff | Penelope Dexter |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 26 | Staff | Tony Bacitari |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 27 | Staff | Yurei Gambino |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 28 | Staff | Cleetus Johnson |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 29 | Staff | Jojo Rodriguez |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 30 | Staff | Liv Laufluv |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 31 | Staff | Walter Dillard |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 32 | Trial Phase | William Ormond |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 33 | Trial Phase | Veronica Blake |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 34 | Trial Phase | Kate Smith |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |
| 35 | Trial Phase | Sierra Foster |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | $0 |

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)